# Regex Match and Replace for Query Builder

Tags: javascript, regex, mongodb

I am having issues with constructing regex in a way so that it will match common math operators `>=, <=, <, >, =, !` in a string such as: `>=10<50!45` but also identify the characters that come after matching one of these.

This is the part I am having issues with. How can I have regex not only find matches based on my set but also record the value that comes afterwards so that I can build out queries using this information.

An resulting regex and replace from my example above would be something like: `{$gte: 10}, {$lt: 50}, {$ne: 45}`

Comment: Are you looking for floating point numbers as well?

Answer (score 0):

`(>=|>|<|<=|!|=)(\d+\.?\d+?)` <---- this pattern captures the operators and numbers separately. [As you can see here](https://regex101.com/r/qBlF62/15). It also works with floating point numbers.

To build the query from the results, just evaluate the 1st group to determine the operator, and evaluate the 2nd group for the value.

Comment: Thank you so very much, this is exactly what I needed! I wish I could up vote this but I lack reputation sadly

Answer (score 0):

This is improved version with some fixes to the `=` and allow for single digit character.

It also takes into consideration spaces.

`/(\>|\<|\!|[\!\<\>]?\=)(\s*?\d+\.?\d*?)/`

https://regexfiddler.com/e/pir1uy2s9wwh/match-for-math-operators